# Converting a string that looks like a list [dictionary] to python list [dictionary] type data

Tags: python, json, string, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert this string data that looks a lot like a list containing dictionaries, into an actual data of said data type or any other form that I can retrieve information. To put it into multiple lines for better view, the string looks like this.

```
[
    {"type": "account", "data": "{\bid\:8,\acc_num\:135}"},
    {"type": "card", "data": "{\card_num\:142}"}
]
```

I've tried the common `json.loads(a, strict=False)` and `json.loads(a)` but it had errors as below. I hoped the `"{\bid\:8,\acc_num\:135}"` part to be lumped into a string (as a value to the key `data`) but maybe it didn't happen... Thought it might be the `\` in the string causing this problem but `a=a.replace('\','')`
is not valid as well (`SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` error).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "a.py", line 55, in <module>
    a=json.loads(a)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 32 (char 31)
```

Comment: You have to escape the backslash in the `replace()` call: `a=a.replace('\\','')`

Comment: @John: That won't solve the problem which is due to the fact that many of the `'\'` characters aren't actually in the string—there they are the ASCII value of corresponding character (see table of recognized Standard C-like escape sequences in the [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) section of the documentation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you could use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to do this—but you'll need to use it *twice*, something like what's shown below which uses a dictionary to "unescape" any standard string backslash escaped characters encountered (while leaving others alone).

The central idea is a two-step process:

1. First to turn characters that must have been escaped back into their original unescaped format (which contains the `\` character).
2. Then replace the `\` character in that with a quote character.

For example the character `'x\08'`—a backspace—is first changed into `'\b'`, then into `'"b'`.

```
from ast import literal_eval

translate = {
    '\\': r'"',   # Backslash (\)
    '\'': r"'",   # Single quote (')
    '\"': r'"',   # Double quote (")
    '\a': r'"a',  # ASCII Bell (BEL)
    '\b': r'"b',  # ASCII Backspace (BS)
    '\f': r'"f',  # ASCII Formfeed (FF)
    '\n': r'"n',  # ASCII Linefeed (LF)
    '\r': r'"r',  # ASCII Carriage Return (CR)
    '\t': r'"t',  # ASCII Horizontal Tab (TAB)
    '\v': r'"v',  # ASCII Vertical Tab (VT)
}.get  # Function to translate escaped characters back to their original form.

def parse(data):
    def unescaped(s): return ''.join(translate(ch, ch) for ch in s)

    result = []
    for d in literal_eval(data):  # First call.
        for key, value in d.items():
            try:
                d[key] = literal_eval(unescaped(value))  # Second call.
            except ValueError:
                pass
        result.append(d)

    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from textwrap import dedent
    from pprint import pprint

    data = dedent("""\
        [
            {"type": "account", "data": "{\bid\:8,\acc_num\:135}"},
            {"type": "card", "data": "{\card_num\:142}"}
        ]
    """)

    pprint(parse(data))
```

Output:

```
[{'data': {'acc_num': 135, 'bid': 8}, 'type': 'account'},
 {'data': {'card_num': 142}, 'type': 'card'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> s = """[
...     {"type": "account", "data": "{\bid\:8,\acc_num\:135}"},
...     {"type": "card", "data": "{\card_num\:142}"}
... ]"""
>>> import ast
>>> x = ast.literal_eval(s)
>>> x
[{'type': 'account', 'data': '{\x08id\\:8,\x07cc_num\\:135}'}, {'type': 'card', 'data': '{\\card_num\\:142}'}]
>>> x[0]
{'type': 'account', 'data': '{\x08id\\:8,\x07cc_num\\:135}'}
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question because `ast.literal_eval()` alone doesn't produce the desired result.